# How to input data of two sets of matrix from a text file and add them?

Tags: c++, matrix, fstream

I am **very new** to C++ but I was given quite a heavy assignment by my lecturer. The assignment is to create a program using C++ which can:

**Input data from a text file into a matrix form and add them together, then printing the answer.**

I tried to do it manually using 3x3 matrix but couldn't even run it. I tried searching Youtube and other sources but there's seem to be no answer to my question. Bare in mind that this is my 3rd week from the first time I'm using C++, so I am a novice programmer. Things I don't understand:

1. Why **can't C++ open my "input.txt"** file. (the spelling is correct and only black screen appear). I assume that this is caused by Avast AntiVirus because sometimes it might block the application from running well.
2. Is it possible to input more than 3x3 matrix?
3. My program looks stupid, but can somebody please point out which code that I get wrong?

Code:

```
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q;
    int r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z;

    ifstream file_("mytext.txt");
    if(file_.is_open())
    (
        while(file_ >> i >> j >> k >> l >> m >> n >> o >> p >> q >> r >> s >> t >> u >> v >> w >> x >> y >> z)
        (
        cout << "The matrix is: ";
        cout << i + r << j + s << k + t << l + u << m + v << n + w << o + x << p + y << q + z; 
        )
    file_.close();
    )
return 0;
}
```

Comment: *Statement blocks* containing multiple C++ statements should be surrounded by `{` and `}` , not `(` and `)`.  You have one for your `if` and another for your `while` - both need to be fixed.  Separately, you should add `<< std::endl` to your second `cout` statement so it flushes the output to screen.  It's also a good idea to add an `else cout << "unable to open file\n";` to your `if`, so you can see if that's ever a problem.

Comment: There's nothing special about doing a bunch of different things. Just do them one thing at a time, and make sure THAT works before you do the next thing.